# C, Structs malloc and pointers. im lost

Tags: c, pointers, struct, readfile

Ok, I'm a bit stuck with malloc and structs it seems >P

```
#include ****
#include "func.h"

int main()
{
  struct fileData *fileData = (struct fileData*)malloc(sizeof(struct fileData));
  fileData->filePath = "text";
  printf(%c\n, *fileData->filePath);
}
```

In the func.h file:

```
#ifndef func
#define func

typedef struct fileData
{
  char *filePath;
  char *input;
  int *numbers;
}
```

It only prints the first 'T' then the program stops, I cant figure out how its supposed to be, I've tried for a while now haha

what I want to do is having a struct that contains a file path picked after the program is run, then read that text file and fill char *input with the whole input then collect all the numbers from input and store it as int in numbers..
I already have the functions running tho.. i can read from a  file, i just have problem getting the struct running.

Comment: Read the documentation, %c is character. use %s. :)

Comment: In the h file you have struc, should be struct. That's a typedef, so you don't need struct keyword in c file. Your print has a %c format specifier, should be %s. Fix those and it should be pretty right. If you still have issues I can give a complete answer.

Comment: thanks, it was ofc the %s that should be there, and what made me so confused was another bug caused by an uninitiated variable. thanks for the help

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
printf(%c\n, *fileData->filePath);
```

won't compile, you don't have any quotes around the first argument.

Fixing that, we get:

```
printf("%c\n", *fileData->filePath);
```

which will print exactly one character, the character found by following the `fileData->filePath` pointer.

If you wanted to print the full name, you should use `%s`:

```
printf("%s\n", fileData->filePath);
```

Note how the asterisk was dropped, since now we pass the address of the string's first character to `printf()`.

Also, [please don't cast the return value of `malloc()` in C](https://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/28169).

Comment: `fileData->filePath ="text";` Is this OK??

Comment: @MadHatter Yes, but you should make `filePath` have the type `const char *` to clarify that it is meant to point at string literals. If the string is acquired at run-time, you must think about memory ownership.

Comment: thanks for the answer, the"" was left out cause i retyped the code and simply forgot em. I was kind of tired and missed an unititated variable that caused some wierd stuff to happen. its fixed and all the suggestions like not casting is implemented, thanks